# how to read an excel file using pandad pd.read_excel in databricks from /Filestore/tables/ directory?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, databricks

Hi I am trying to read an excel file that's uploaded to DBX filestore from UI. I can see that file is available under /Filestore/tables directory and I am trying to create a pandas dataframe using the code below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/abc.xlsx")
display(df)
```

I am getting the error below

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/abc.xlsx

I understand that the path is not relative to my current working directory I would like to know how can I point to the file from the file store using python

things I have tried:

I have used /FileStore/tables/abc.xlsx in the path and it didn't work

I know the scala code with spark-excel jar works but I cant execute scala commands as my org didn't and will not provide me access to execute scala commands.

any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: are you using community edition?

Answer (score -1):

The file is not stored as an excel file when you create a table. You access the data via the [Spark API](https://docs.databricks.com/data/tables.html#language-python).

You could also read the table into a koalas dataframe and then convert it to pandas if you don't want to use koalas.

If you don't want to use Spark or koalas, then upload the file to /dbfs/FileStore and use read_excel from the file in that location.